# Generate table from JSON

Tags: visualforce, javascript

My apex controller returns this JSON object with the name of the product:id ( if we have no id is that the product is unvalid.

```
{
\"SKE-95\":null,
\"RG-9323\":\"a003000000IOGm3AAH\",
\"SDF-5022\":\"a003000000IOGliAAH\",
\"HGT-3531\":\"a003000000IOGldAAH\",
\"DE-5430\":\"a003000000IOGjwAAH\"
}
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to generate a table with javascript that looks like:

---

| name    | status |

ske-95 | unvalid

sdf-5022| valid

....

---

Comment: are you using remote action to return above json object?

Comment: @Himanshu no I'm using an actionfunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON format (assuming the backslashes are not actually present) you have is not ideal because although you can use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop over those values in JavaScript the ordering will be arbitrary which is probably not what you want. An array of objects would make more sense so you could loop over the elements in index order:

```
[
    {"SKE-95":null},
    {"RG-9323":"a003000000IOGm3AAH"},
    {"SDF-5022":"a003000000IOGliAAH"},
    {"HGT-3531":"a003000000IOGldAAH"},
    {"DE-5430":"a003000000IOGjwAAH"}
]
```

You can create arrays/lists and maps in Apex to achieve the ordering you need when you [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize).

For such a simple table, to create the table in JavaScript you don't need anything more than the raw [DOM methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) to add the table, table rows and table cells.